# Sending an e-mail notification when a specific list item value changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, alert, notifications

Looking to set up a workflow that will automatically send an e-mail only when a specific value in a list is changed.

I'm able to get it functioning with one of the template workflows that alert when an item is modified, but it's causing notification bloat and I really only need it to alert when a specific value in the list is modified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about MS Flow/Power Automate or Designer Workflow?

Comment: MS Flow/Power Automate

Answer (score 0):

To check in MS Flow/Power Automate whether a list items' value of a particular column has been changed, all previous versions of the item can be retrieved using a [Send a HTTP request..] action and compare the current value with the previous values.

I've already posted a similar response in [this forum](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284466/capture-static-date-time-when-list-item-status-column-changed-to-6-complete/284490#284490). Please take a look into it and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post with similar request for your reference:
[Send an Alert only when a specific column changes.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-an-Alert-only-when-a-specific-column-changes/td-p/106153)

As is suggested in the post, you can use an additional column to compare with the column values to be followed, and send an email if they do not match the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete MS Flow/Power Automate example showing how to send alert email when a specific column value is changed. In the example, the current value is compared with the previous value by retrieving item's **versions** from the history using [Send an HTTP request..]

Please see the screenshots and explanation below

**MS Flow triggers by [When an item is created or modified]**, and
at the beginning of the Flow, a check is made to verify if the item was modified and then proceeds

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Expressions 1 and 2

```
1. varPrevComments

if(empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][1]['Comments']), '', body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][1]['Comments'])

2. varCurrentComments

if(empty(body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][0]['Comments']), '', body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][0]['Comments'])
```

### Detail 2

[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.