# How can I delete a list item if it keeps the same status after 7 days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a list with a column named "Status". With a workflow, I would like to delete an item if it keeps the same status after 7 days. If the status changes, then the item would not be deleted.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've already responded to a similar question in this forum [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284466/capture-static-date-time-when-list-item-status-column-changed-to-6-complete/284490#284490). Please review and let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using MS Flow/Power Automate, we can achieve this by adding a [Delay] action in the flow.
Assuming there will be a final Status, when the item is permanent, and will not be deleted. In this example, the final status=Active.

Please refer to the screenshots below and let me know if you have any questions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you. Please mark the question as answered. Thanks-Matiur