# How to count how much time a status column is on a certain value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate how much time a certain status took to complete/move on to the next one. Basically, I have 6 choices and I want to know how much time it took to pass from one status to another. The thing is the status can be altered even if it is completed. For example, I'm at level 4 status and there was a problem and I have to go back to Level 3 Status.
This will automatically mess up with my time.

I don't have a single idea how to do this and all my searches haven't been successful. Can someone just point me to the right direction, maybe share some links that may help?

Comment: Take a look into this Power Automate (MS Flows) [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284466/capture-static-date-time-when-list-item-status-column-changed-to-6-complete/284471#284471)

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using a second list or datavese table to track the changes.

If the status now is greater than before, then track change. You could decrease the count if you need to reset the count if the item is moved from 4 to 3.

You can trigger a flow on a field change, but I've abandoned using it due to it being extremely unreliable in high-traffic lists. Flows run on timers, so if something happens between the user updating a value and the flow running, you can miss updates.

Some ideas from the land of Google:
https://www.google.com/search?&q=sharepoint+track+when+field+changes